# Re-Include Module

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I need some like this:

```
module One
  def test; puts 'Test One'; end
end

module Two
  def test; puts 'Test Two'; end
end

class Foo
  include One
  include Two
  include One
end
```

In this case I need as a result 'Test One' but obviously it returns 'Test Two'. I need a clean simple way for re-include my module.

Any suggestion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 class Module
     def include_again(mod)
         mod.instance_methods.each { |m|
             self.send(:define_method, m) { |*args|
                 mod.instance_method(m).bind(self).call(*args)
             }
         }
     end
 end

module One
    def test(a); puts "test one #{a}"; end
end

module Two
    def test; puts "test two"; end
end

class Foo
    include One
    include Two
end

Foo.new.test #=> "test two"

class Foo
    include_again One
end

Foo.new.test(1) #=> "test one 1"
```

Comment: What's happen if my method test has arguments ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not precisely sure of a workaround other than [`remove_method`](http://peter.michaux.ca/articles/ruby-s-module-remove_method-and-inheritance-in-javascript), but the reason *why* what you've shown doesn't work is the way that Ruby performs method lookup.

Inspecting `Foo`'s `ancestors` during each step of `Foo`'s creation gives us a big hint:

```
module One
  def test; puts 'Test One'; end
end

module Two
  def test; puts 'Test Two'; end
end

class Foo
  include One
  p ancestors
  include Two
  p ancestors
  include One
  p ancestors
end
```

Output:

```
[Foo, One, Object, Kernel]
[Foo, Two, One, Object, Kernel]
[Foo, Two, One, Object, Kernel]
```

If a module is already in a class's ancestry, Ruby doesn't allow you to re-include it again.  Thus, when `Two` is included *after* `One`, `Two` occurs in `Foo`'s lookup table before `One` has a chance, no matter how many times you re-include `One`.

Comment: remove_method won't work because the method isn't defined on `Foo` but in a module included by `Foo` (and i assume you dont wnat to remove the method from the module ;) )

Answer (score 0):

You could adjust the behavior of include:

```
module One
  def test; puts 'Test One'; end
end

module Two
  def test; puts 'Test Two'; end
end

class Foo
  @mods = []
  def self.include(mod)
    @mods.delet mod
    @mods << mod
  end

  def self.new(*args)
    super.tap { |o| @mods.each { |m| o.extend m } } 
  end

  include One
  include Two
  include One
end
```

Comment: Yeah, that's to write it in one line. it's like smalltalk's 'yourself'. What is the alternative (non-abusive) use case of tap?

Comment: i haven't used #tap much myself, but the guys i've spoken to say its only real use case is for debugging (they said they would not use it in production code).

Answer (score 0):

@banister, many thanks for that answer, since I can't comment I'll add here the code to make it work with blocks as well as arguments:

```
class Module
  def include_again(mod)
    mod.instance_methods.each{ |m| 
      self.send(:define_method, m) { |*args, &block|
        mod.instance_method(m).bind(self).call(*args, &block)
      }
    }
  end
end
```